# Simplify three way comparison a < b < c || b < c < a || c < a < b;

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

Is there a shorter way to compute this boolean expression?

`a < b < c || b < c < a || c < a < b`

In JavaScript this would be:

`a < b && b < c || b < c && c < a || c < a && a < b`

Is there some useful maths or boolean algebra trick which would make this less cumbersome?

`a`, `b` and `c` are all numbers. In my particular use case, they are guaranteed to be distinct.

(For additional context, it arose in the process of answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269089/identify-start-and-end-of-arc-out-of-three-points-angles/68573462#68573462))

Comment: Are `a`,`b`,`c` numbers?

Comment: I'd just do `isAscending(a, b, c) || isAscending(b, c, a) || isAscending(c, a, b)` where `isAscending = (a, b, c) => a < b && b < c`.

Comment: I think if they are numbers or other, this is not the question. What matters is that there is an order relationship

Comment: `a < b && (b < c || c < a) || b < c && c < a` is shorter but less obvious ... sometimes the best code is not the shortest

Comment: If all numbers are distinct, `((a < b) ^ (b < c) ^ (c < a)) === 0` is probably a start.

Comment: I've only had two coffees so forgive me if this is dumb, but under what circumstances can this _not_ be true?  Perhaps it's better to use those to test instead?

Comment: @Martin what if a = b = c :p

Comment: @Martin `a = 3, b = 2, c = 1` would be false.

Comment: Thanks, sorry just to clarify what I meant was "_is this a situation where testing for the negative outcomes is easier than testing for the positive ones_"?

Comment: Added some more details. @Martin: No. The two situations are equally likely.

Comment: @Martin OP is testing if three variables are in ascending order. And doing three times by rotating them. The *opposite* would be if the values are in *descending* order or they are *equal*. That's *at least* the same amount of comparisons.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I *think* that works. Can you verify/prove and write it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty convinced. The three expressions can't all be true. And the xor will return false if two of them are true, which is exactly what the original statement is testing. Can be shortened further to `!((a < b) ^ (b < c) ^ (c < a))`

Comment: Or even (without having to worry about whether bitwise xor is the same as boolean xor): (a < b) + (b < c) + (c < a) === 2

Comment: @VLAZ It's not though is it, because if `(a >= b || b >= c)` then that would solve that case, which is many less operations than the original equation

Comment: @SteveBennett are these going to have a constant ratio to them? e.g, `1`, `2`, 3`, or `2`, `4`, `6` or similar? If so, you'd also be able to drop them to a common base, e.g., `-1`, `0`, and `1` then check check them against a precomputed table of results.

Comment: @Martin if `a > b` then `b < c < a` might still be valid. E.g. `a = 3,  b = 1, c = 2`

Comment: No, no assumptions like that - other than they are (in this case) all in the range -PI...PI

Comment: @VLAZ In which case it simply becomes `!(a >= b && b >= c && c >= a)`. Although `b < c < a` couldn't be true anyway if `b >= c` so it becomes superfluous

Comment: @Martin [no, it doesn't work](https://jsbin.com/cobunuh/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 different boolean comparisons out of which you want 2 to hold. (Strictly, 2 or more, but in your case you can never have all 3). So you can write

```
a < b && b < c || b < c && c < a || c < a && a < b
```

as

```
(a < b) + (b < c) + (c < a) == 2
```